# Using <symbol/> to render a group of SVG's

Tags: html, css, svg

I just fixed it, but I am not 100% sure I did it right.

Before it was using a `<g>` element,

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/vhymcfrb/

Then I removed that and replaced it with `<symbol>` because that was what was recommended I use.

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/oLhjzfe2/3/

Did I do this right, or do I need to make more adjustments?

I added this to the CSS:

```
.container-left .wraph .nav li svg {
  width: 198px;
  height: 198px;  
}
```

And I set up `<symbol>` like this

```
          <svg class="alpha">
             <symbol id="play" width="198" height="198" viewbox="8.5 -12.2 7 48.49">
                <title>Play</title>
                <path d="M16.036 11.58l-6-3.82a.5.5 0 0 0-.77.42v7.64a.498.498 0 0 0 .77.419l6-3.817c.145-.092.23-.25.23-.422s-.085-.33-.23-.42z" />
                <path d="M12 22.75C6.072 22.75 1.25 17.928 1.25 12S6.072 1.25 12 1.25 22.75 6.072 22.75 12 17.928 22.75 12 22.75zm0-20C6.9 2.75 2.75 6.9 2.75 12S6.9 21.25 12 21.25s9.25-4.15 9.25-9.25S17.1 2.75 12 2.75z" />
             </symbol>
             <use href="#play" />
          </svg>
          <div class="hide">
             <div class="video playinga" data-id="ZPz3wzPlruA"></div>
          </div>
       </li>
       <li>
          <svg  class="beta">
             <use href="#play" />
          </svg>
          <div class="hide">
             <div class="video playingb" data-id="VFMtNOxpV3o"></div>
          </div>
       </li>
```

And here is the full code all written out.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #353198;
}

.container-left .wraph .nav li svg {
  width: 198px;
  height: 198px;
   
}

.outer {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.tcell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

svg {
  border: solid;
}

.container-left {
  float: left;
  width: 606px;
  margin: 0;
}

.container-left .wraph {
  position: relative;
  width: 606px;
  margin: 45px 0 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 3px solid #0059dd;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-position: 0 -600px;
  background-size: 100% 200%;
}

.container-left .wraph .nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.container-left .wraph .nav li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
}

.container-left .wraph .nav li {
  float: left;
  width: 198px;
  height: 198px;
  margin: 0 0 3px 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.container-left .wraph .nav li:nth-of-type(3n+2) {
  margin: 0 3px 0 3px;
}

.container-left .wraph .nav li:nth-of-type(n+7) {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.container-left .wraph .nav li svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  fill: blue;
}




.container-left .wraph .linesa::before,
.container-left .wraph .linesa::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 198px;
  width: 3px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #0059dd;
}

.container-left .wraph .linesa::after {
  left: 399px;
}

.container-left .wraph .linesb::before,
.container-left .wraph .linesb::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 198px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: #0059dd;
}

.container-left .wraph .linesb::after {
  top: 399px;
}

.container-left .wraph .nav li iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 198px;
  height: 198px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container-left .wraph .nav li .alpha,
.playinga {
  margin: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
}

.container-left .wraph .nav li .beta,
.playingb {
  margin: 0 201px 0;
}

.container-left .wraph .nav li .gamma,
.playingc {
  margin: 0 402px 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
}

.container-left .wraph .nav li .delta,
.playingd {
  margin: 201px 0 0;
}

.container-left .wraph .nav li .epsilon,
.playinge {
  margin: 201px 201px 0;
}

.container-left .wraph .nav li .zeta,
.playingf {
  margin: 201px 402px 0;
}

.container-left .wraph .nav li .eta,
.playingg {
  margin: 402px 0 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
}

.container-left .wraph .nav li .theta,
.playingh {
  margin: 402px 201px 0;
}

.container-left .wraph .nav li .iota,
.playingi {
  margin: 402px 402px 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
}


a:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
   <div class="tcell">
      <div class="container-left">
         <div class=" wraph">
            <ul class="nav">
               <li>
                  <svg class="alpha">
                     <symbol id="play" width="198" height="198" viewbox="8.5 -12.2 7 48.49">
                        <title>Play</title>
                        <path d="M16.036 11.58l-6-3.82a.5.5 0 0 0-.77.42v7.64a.498.498 0 0 0 .77.419l6-3.817c.145-.092.23-.25.23-.422s-.085-.33-.23-.42z" />
                        <path d="M12 22.75C6.072 22.75 1.25 17.928 1.25 12S6.072 1.25 12 1.25 22.75 6.072 22.75 12 17.928 22.75 12 22.75zm0-20C6.9 2.75 2.75 6.9 2.75 12S6.9 21.25 12 21.25s9.25-4.15 9.25-9.25S17.1 2.75 12 2.75z" />
                     </symbol>
                     <use href="#play" />
                  </svg>
                  <div class="hide">
                     <div class="video playinga" data-id="ZPz3wzPlruA"></div>
                  </div>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <svg  class="beta">
                     <use href="#play" />
                  </svg>
                  <div class="hide">
                     <div class="video playingb" data-id="VFMtNOxpV3o"></div>
                  </div>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <svg  class="gamma">
                     <use href="#play" />
                  </svg>
                  <div class="hide">
                     <div class="video playingc" data-id="Zkf4EDjV1_g"></div>
                  </div>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <svg  class="delta">
                     <use href="#play" />
                  </svg>
                  <div class="hide">
                     <div class="video playingd" data-id="-Xgi_way56U"></div>
                  </div>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <svg class="epsilon">
                     <use href="#play" />
                  </svg>
                  <div class="hide">
                     <div class="video playinge" data-id="EK3h0IADYrQ"></div>
                  </div>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <svg class="zeta">
                     <use href="#play" />
                  </svg>
                  <div class="hide">
                     <div class="video playingf" data-id="YOw9J4K02H4"></div>
                  </div>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <svg class="eta">
                     <use href="#play" />
                  </svg>
                  <div class="hide">
                     <div class="video playingg" data-id="ID856YDIb6A"></div>
                  </div>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <svg class="theta">
                     <use href="#play" />
                  </svg>
                  <div class="hide">
                     <div class="video playingh" data-id="9Gn8ymkrlbI"></div>
                  </div>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <svg class="iota">
                     <use href="#play" />
                  </svg>
                  <div class="hide">
                     <div class="video playingi" data-id="qYEooPeyz5M"></div>
                  </div>
               </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="linesa"></div>
            <div class="linesb"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It depends what you're trying to achieve? What difference has <symbol> vs <g> made and is that what you wanted or not?

Comment: This is how the code was set up using <g> element. https://jsfiddle.net/oLhjzfe2/3/

Comment: OK, so what is your question? What are you trying to achieve? What difference is there between what you've got and what you want in either case?